# Bi directional reactivity between filters

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application where I am using update function so that filters are reactive with respect to each other. Not sure there is some issue in the code. The values are not reflecting here as expected (for example for "Rat" as 1, we cannot select "No" in another filter ("New") Can anyone help me here?

Is there any alternate way?

```
library(shiny)

data_13_Sam  <- data.frame(
  Ratings = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), flag = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(offset = 0, width = 1,uiOutput("rat")),
  column(offset = 0, width = 2, uiOutput("nt")),
  tableOutput('data')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$rat <- renderUI({
    selectInput("rat1",label = tags$h4("Rat"),choices = unique(data_13_Sam$Ratings))
  })
  
  output$nt <- renderUI({
    selectInput("nt1",label = tags$h4("New"),choices = unique(data_13_Sam$flag))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$rat1,  {
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "nt1", choices = unique(data_13_Sam$flag[data_13_Sam$Ratings == input$rat1]))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nt1,  {
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "rat1", choices = unique(data_13_Sam$Ratings[data_13_Sam$flag == input$nt1]))
  })
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please check your dataframe.  When ratings=1, flag is c(Yes, No)

Comment: Yes. But when u run this code. It acts differently.

Comment: It is behaving as expected.  I do not see any issue in your code.  Perhaps you should create a different dummy dataframe.

Comment: Is it. I’m getting the error. Very strange

Comment: No I tried restarting, Well please check this . When you open the application, by default its 1 and "Yes" right? Now when you select "No" the first filter changes to 2. Make sense?

Comment: Yes.  The first value of ratings when flag is "No" is 2.  That is fine.  Also, if you select 5 as your ratings, you will notice that it only has "Yes" as the choice.  Which is how the dataframe is set-up.

Comment: Yes exactly. The first value of ratings when flag is "No" is 2. So we cannot select/see 1 and "No" right? So meaning not getting what we want :)

Comment: No, possible selections are 2,4,1,3.  You can still select 1.  However, if you want to display 1,2,3,4, you need to sort it.

Comment: No YBS :( We cannot select both No and 1. Please try :) Can you please try once for me. You are telling You can still select 1 with No in another filter right. But it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with `shiny::selectInput`, and removing second `updateSelectInput(...)`   Please see code below.

```
library(shiny)

data_13_Sam  <- data.frame(
  Ratings = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), flag = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(offset = 0, width = 1,uiOutput("rat")),
  column(offset = 0, width = 2, uiOutput("nt")),
  tableOutput('data')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$rat <- renderUI({
    shiny::selectInput("rat1",label = tags$h4("Rat"),choices = unique(data_13_Sam$Ratings))
  })

  output$nt <- renderUI({
    shiny::selectInput("nt1",label = tags$h4("New"),choices = unique(data_13_Sam$flag))
  })


  observeEvent(input$rat1,  {
    shiny::updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "nt1", choices = unique(data_13_Sam$flag[data_13_Sam$Ratings == input$rat1]))
  })

  # observeEvent(input$nt1,  {
  #   shiny::updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "rat1", choices = unique(data_13_Sam$Ratings[data_13_Sam$flag == input$nt1]))
  # })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: See when you select 1, its changes to Yes. You see it? But in dataframe 1 has both "Yes" and "No"

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem here.  1 has a choice of Yes, No.  It will show Yes first as that is the way your dataframe is set-up.

Comment: Yes your right. But the user should be able to select "No" for 1 also right?. I am planning to put a dataframe below as per the filter. Basically, why the user should be able to select 1 and No

Comment: I see.  I think that is due to the `updateSelectInput` being bi-directional.

Comment: Yes, This is the big challenge I am facing here . Trying a lot to solve this. Can you please try to solve this

Comment: If you remove the second `observeEvent`, it works fine.

Comment: Like??? Can you share the code? But I do not think it will be bi directional

Comment: Nope this does not work as well. Leave its ok :) I will try to figure out. Thanks for the help